# How to publish Chrome extension to my domain users without paying registration fee?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I haven't paid the "one-time developer registration fee" and I have uploaded my extension. In my developer dashboard it says.

"The fee is not required to publish only to users in mydomain.com"

How can I publish to users only in mydomain.com without paying the "one-time developer registration fee". I can't find that option anywhere.

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1375694?hl=en). Is this what you mean?

Comment: That legend refers to this procedure: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

Answer (score 6):

To be able to publish to only people in your domain, you must have this permission enabled by the Google Apps for Work administrator for your organization.

From Google: "Administrators can choose which users they want to be able to publish private apps for their organization by clicking this checkbox in the Admin console under Device management > Chrome management > User settings > Chrome Web Store Permissions."

Once this permission has been enabled, you can upload the ZIP file, for your extension, fill out the form, and at the end, select Private (Everyone at yourdomain.com) under Visibility options. This will allow you to publish without paying the fee.

See their documentation here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

Comment: I tried this. It just keeps asking for five dollars :-(

Comment: It might have been that it takes a long time for the change to Chrome Web Store Permissions takes effect. I came in the next day and saw a new option on the store dashboard. Unfortunately, I had already given up and paid at this point.

Comment: well five bucks isn't too bad @AndrewShepherd :p

Answer (score 1):

Based on: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html

Once you package your extension (Go to  and click the developer mode checkbox. Now you should see the packaging button), you upload it to your server. Now you will need to use the appropriate HTTP headers to get Chrome to recognize your extension (A .crx on your server) as an installable. Chrome considers a file to be installable if:

- The file has the content type application/x-chrome-extension
- The file suffix is .crx and both of the following are true:

  - The file is not served with the HTTP header X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  - The file is served with one of the following content types:

    - empty string
    - "text/plain"
    - "application/octet-stream"
    - "unknown/unknown"
    - "application/unknown"
    - "*/*"

Comment: Support for off-store CRX files are being phased out for Windows, see http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html

Comment: @RobW Well there goes all my work on extensions. I'm not paying $5 just to host extensions that my peers and I use. However, it is for a good reason.

Comment: You can still load unpacked extensions via Developer mode, though auto-update won't work.